# How to remove headers (colnames) after combining several csv files

Tags: r

I want to combine data from several csv files with the same format so I can analyse them, but I cannot remove the headers/column names from the several combined files.

I have used the `lapply` function in order to take a list of the context of all these files and it looks something like:

```
ID X1 X2 ---> header of 1st csv file
1  5  6
2  6  9
.......
10 7  8
```

.

```
ID X1 X2 --> headers 2nd csv file
1  5  6
2  6  9
.......
10 7  8
e.t.c
```

How can I remove the header characters in order to apply mathematical operations to these data?

My code:

```
data<-lapply(files, read.csv)
mean <-(mean(data$column2, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I also tried `read.csv(headers=FALSE)` but R do not accept this when the function is inside the lapply

I expect the mean of the data frame of the combined files but I get the error:

> In mean.default(data$column2, na.rm = TRUE) :   argument is not
>   numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: In your example `data`is a list of dataframes. Eventually you want something like `sapply(data, function(d) mean(d$X2))` or `sapply(data, function(d) mean(d[[3]]))`

Answer (score 0):

You can import your data directly without column names:

```
read_matrix <- function (csvfile) {
    a <- read.csv(csvfile, header=FALSE)
    matrix(as.matrix(a), ncol=ncol(a), dimnames=NULL)
}
df <-  read_matrix('even_iops_Jan15.csv')
```

An other option is setting them to null:

```
names(df) <- NULL
```

Comment: This just converted every number into a chracter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have read the `data` correctly with headers I think what you'll need to do is first extract the columns and then take the `mean`.

You can extract the column

1) By name

```
mean(sapply(data, `[[`, 'column2'), na.rm = TRUE)
```

2) By position

```
mean(sapply(data, `[[`, 2), na.rm = TRUE)
```

With `lapply` you need to `unlist` the data first

```
mean(unlist(lapply(data, `[[`, 'column2')), na.rm = TRUE)
```